# Can not GET JSON data with API created by Django

Tags: ios, json, django, swift, alamofire

I want to get the json data using the API created by Django and show it in the table view.
There is nothing in value in the following program. What should I do?

Json data:

```
{
"books": [
{
  "id": 1, 
  "name": "Django", 
  "publisher": "GeekLab Nagano", 
  "page": 10, 
  "impressions": []
}]}
```

Code:

```
var tableTitle = [String]()
var tableDetail = [String]()

let url:String = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/"

func loadData() {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON {
        response in

        guard let value = response.result.value else {
            return
        }
        let json = JSON(value)
        let books = json["books"]

        for item in books.arrayValue {
            self.tableTitle.append(item["name"].stringValue)
            self.tableDetail.append(item["publisher"].stringValue)
        }

        print(self.tableTitle)
        print(self.tableDetail)


        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably ios blocked that http:// request. You may find answer to fix that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Comment: That URL will only work in the simulator if you are running a web server against port 8000 on your Mac.

Comment: Please provide Django side urls also

Comment: It worked with the simulator, but it didn't work on the actual machine.

Comment: Well you've hard coded the localhost address, so naturally it won't work outside your dev machine.

Comment: It was bad to use a local host address. It resolved. thank you.